# Next.js 13 - Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js, Even next.config.js does not have the target property

Tags: next.js

I upgraded my next.js app to Next.js 13 and pushed the new version to AWS Amplify. The build failed due to this error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js

`Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js. See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deprecated-target-config at Object.loadConfig [as default (/codebuild/output/src405507991/src/assistian/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:97:19)`

Here is my next.config.js with no target:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })
    return config
  }
}
```

Any opinion on what is going wrong?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be unsupported at this time as per https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/41932

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/update-app-nextjs-version.html, need to migrate to Amplify Hosting compute for NextJS 13 (I use SSR). My Amplify was created before release of Amplify Hosting compute (~ November 2022)

Answer (score 1):

Amplify currently supports NextJS versions greater than version 11, via a migration. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/update-app-nextjs-version.html